# What's the translation of "paleoburrow" in French?

Tags: traduction, histoire, science, zoologie

A paleoburrow [is an](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Paleoburrow&oldid=968438962):

> underground shelter ([tunnel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunnel), [burrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burrow), lair, etc.) excavated by extinct paleo-vertebrate [megafauna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megafauna) (i.e., giant mammals, such as [ground sloths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_sloths)) that lived in the [prehistoric era](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prehistory).[[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Paleoburrow&oldid=968438962#cite_note-1)[[2]](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Paleoburrow&oldid=968438962#cite_note-2)[[3]](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Paleoburrow&oldid=968438962#cite_note-AJenn-lost-3)

Example from {1}:

[image]

What's the translation of "paleoburrow" in French?

[Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/?sl=en&tl=fr&text=Paleoburrow&op=translate) and [Linguee](https://www.linguee.com/english-french/search?source=auto&query=Paleoburrow) didn't help.

[image]

---

References:

- {1} Lopes, Renato Pereira, Heinrich Theodor Frank, Francisco Sekiguchi de Carvalho Buchmann, and Felipe Caron. "Megaichnus igen. nov.: giant paleoburrows attributed to extinct Cenozoic mammals from South America." Ichnos 24, no. 2 (2017): 133-145. [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=Megaichnus+igen.+nov.%3A+Giant+Paleoburrows+Attributed+to+Extinct+Cenozoic+Mammals+from+South+America&btnG=); [PDF](https://web.archive.org/web/20211117061351/https://repositorio.unesp.br/bitstream/handle/11449/162902/WOS000403834800004.pdf?sequence=1).

Comment: After checking your "unfructuous" Google find, I saw that in fact you overlooked something.

Comment: @LPH but only one serious webpage used "Paléoterrier" from what I recall, so it seemed more like a (good) neologism.

Comment: @LPH Sorry I got confused. Here's what happened: https://translate.google.com/?sl=en&tl=fr&text=Paleoburrow&op=translate told me "Paléobule" (which nobody seems to use). I then thought of Paleoterrier (instead of Pal*é*oterrier), but without the accent I could find only 1 serious webpage when Googling for it. Interestingly my Google Translate on Android translates Paleoburrow as Paléoterrier, unlike the Google Translate  website on my side,  hence your comment and my previous confusion.

Comment: profil blanchi, crayeux, faible densité, **paléo-terriers de termites à la recherche d’eau**, essentiellement formé d’opale A avec alunite et
gypse - datation K-Ar altération ≈ 8-18 Ma ICI: http://www.paleotime.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/PCR-ARA-2016-volume-2_bd.pdf

Comment: @LPH We say unfruitful or unproductive in English.

Comment: @Lambie https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/unfructuous?

Comment: It's not about whether a word is in a dictionary. In English, we say: "My search has not been fruitful or productive". Or: "My search has been unproductive or unfruitful". You need a really good reason to use unfructuous. It sounds positively Dickensian.

Comment: @Lambie "Unfructuous", when taken literally is obsolete, but taken figuratively, it means exactly "unfruitful" and it is rare (SOED), but not incorrect, and anyone can use it.

Comment: @LPH I do not need English lessons. Thank you. It seems that unfructuous is still quite popular in India and in law means: without any purpose or value: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/infructuous

Comment: @Lambie Who said you needed lessons?  There is the Oxford definition I mentioned, the Collins definition shown to you above, and there is this free Dictionary definition: https://www.thefreedictionary.com/unfructuous I admit it might be rare (I wasn't aware of it), but it can still be used, it is still English. (recent ex., 2011: This social sensitiveness is the ethical basis of good character; without it efficiency, discipline, co- operation and many other fine qualities may either remain unfructuous or may be corrupted for baser purposes.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The term "paleoburrow" started spreading more largely around 2010 when geologists discovered the first such burrows in Brazil and forged the Portuguese word *paleotocas* as a word for word translation from English (*tocas* → tunnel/burrow)<sup>1</sup>.

But it looks as if the word hasn't yet got an acknowledged translation in French. I haven't found a scientific paper on the subject in French yet but  *terrier* is the word that is the most often used when communicating with the general public.

If we look at recent popularisation articles we can find the word *paléoterrier* :

> Il se pourrait qu’aucun paléoterrier n’ait été trouvé dans ces autres régions parce que personne n’en a cherché. Ce domaine de recherche spécifique en est à ses balbutiements, ([Trendcatchers](https://trendscatchers.io/index.php/2019/01/02/des-scientifiques-ont-decouvert-ces-tunnels-geants-avant-de-comprendre-qui-les-avait-creuse/15/), 2019)

Sometimes still used between brackets:

> des marques de griffes qui l'ont conduit à conclure que ce passage serait en réalité "un paléoterrier". Autrement dit, le terrier creusé par une créature fouisseuse il y a des milliers d'années. ([Maxiscience](https://www.maxisciences.com/paleontologie/ces-enormes-tunnels-decouverts-au-bresil-ont-ils-ete-creuses-par-des-creatures-geantes_art39380.html), 2017)

We could make an appropriate guess in saying that in the long run **paléoterrier** – the word for word translation from English and Portuguese – will establish itself in French.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>  [Article](https://www.discovermagazine.com/planet-earth/get-lost-in-mega-tunnels-dug-by-south-american-megafauna#.WOHmjyN95Vf) in *Discovery Magazine*,Mar 28, 2017.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be no specific term, and these lairs would be referred to often as "tunnels".

[Ces tunnels creusés il y a 10 000 ans seraient l’oeuvre de paresseux géants](https://sciencepost.fr/tunnels-seraient-loeuvre-de-paresseux-geants/)

In this second article the term used is "*terrier*", which is a more specific term  ("burrow", "hole", in English).

[Ulyces](https://www.ulyces.co/news/ces-enormes-tunnels-ont-ete-creuses-par-une-espece-disparue-de-paresseux-geants-2/)

Quite conceivably, then, those holes could then be referred to as "*terriers paléolithiques*".

[Ces énormes tunnels découverts au Brésil ont-ils été creusés par des créatures géantes ?](https://www.maxisciences.com/paleontologie/ces-enormes-tunnels-decouverts-au-bresil-ont-ils-ete-creuses-par-des-creatures-geantes_art39380.html)

In the French [Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paresseux_terrestre_de_Jefferson), the term "*terrier géant*" is used (and also "large tunnel").

A specific term to match the English does exist; it is "*paléoterrier*". It is used [here](https://stringfixer.com/fr/Paleoburrow), [here](https://www.soolide.com/11367/14) and [here](https://trendscatchers.io/index.php/2019/01/02/des-scientifiques-ont-decouvert-ces-tunnels-geants-avant-de-comprendre-qui-les-avait-creuse/15/).

Comment: Le suffixe paleo/paléo signifie "ancien" n'est pas ici, à mon avis l’abréviation de paléolithique. Donc le terme terrier paléolithique est plus précis mais non équivalent (ça pourrait dater d'une autre époque préhistorique).

Comment: @XouDo Les paléoterriers se trouvent bien au paléotlithique ; ce sont en fait des terriers du paléolithique supérieur (-35000 ou -40000 à -9500) parce qu'on les situe à -10000. Il me semble donc qu'on parle de la même chose; viendrait-on à en découvrir d'une autre sorte et/ou dans une autre ère ou une autre partie du paléolithique, les deux termes deviendraient alors ambigus, mais pour l'instant on est sûr qu'ils correspondent tous les deux à la même découverte.

Comment: Dans le premier lien, on lit: **Plus de 1.500 "paléoterriers**. Alors, t'as pas lu tout l'article?

Comment: @Lambie Non, pas le premier lien, mais seulement le troisième ; néanmoins, c'est bien le cas, au lieu de tout lire j'ai fait une recherche de termes sans être encore conscient  du mot « paléoterrier ».

Answer (score -1):

Paleo is paleon in French, yet I've never heard of such a word which would be a mix of the previous with Burrow (or something else that means hole, tunnel, etc.). We would most probably use two words or a full sentence to say that in French.

But I think I have the answer you are looking for : terrier.
It means the same thing physically, but the difference is that a terrier also adds up to the fact that this is indead a hole, but that it a vast combination of tunnels instead of a single one. And that it is also home of the creature.
Such as Meerkats by example, who build those terriers.

So either you invent a new word for it like paleonterrier or paleon-terrier, cause there isn't one that exists yet!
Or as I said before you'd refer to it as a terrier dating back from whichever year/era.

Un vieux terrier?
Un terrier primitif?
Un ancien terrier?
Un terrier antique?

Hope this can help!

Comment: *Paleo is paleon in French* what are your sources on this? I'm a native french and I've never heard nor read "paléon" or "paleon". Plus a simple web search shows paléoterrier does exist (maybe a translation from english, but still).